# How to save base64 encoded file in LoopBack within a hook

Tags: node.js, file-upload, base64, loopbackjs, loopback

I'm trying to find a way to save a file in a loopback application that was send as base64 encoded string.

So I have a model with all possible field and also a base64 encoded image, “receipt”.

```
{
  ...modelData,
  "receipt": "datadata:image/jpeg;base64,whatever=="
}
```

So... what I'm thinking of is this

```
Model.beforeRemote('create', function(ctx, model, next) {
  const file = ctx.args.data.receipt;
  app.models.Attachment.upload(...)
  // and replace base64 with returned filename
})
```

But I don't clearly understand how and what should I pass to that upload method. Or maybe it has to be some different approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a remote hook but rather a remote method, yet I believe you can adapt the code to your own needs.

We basically create a remote method called "upload" for `Documents` model and it takes care of uploading it to a predefined container name.

```
const CONTAINERS_URL = '/api/container/';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const encodedFileContainer = 'files';

module.exports = function(Document) {
  Document.upload = function(encodedFile, fileName, cb) {
    let uploadStream = Document.app.models.container.uploadStream(
      encodedFileContainer,
      fileName
    );
    uploadStream.end(encodedFile, 'base64', async err => {
      if (err) return cb(err);
      let newRecord = await Document.create(
        {
          fileName,
          url: CONTAINERS_URL + encodedFileContainer + '/download/' + fileName,
          container: encodedFileContainer
        },
        function(err, obj) {
          if (err !== null) {
            cb(err);
          } else {
            cb(null, obj);
          }
        }
      );
    });
  };
  Document.remoteMethod('upload', {
    description: 'Uploads a file',
    accepts: [
      {
        arg: 'endcodedFile',
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        description: 'base64 encoded file',
        http: {source: 'form'}
      },
      {
        arg: 'fileName',
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        description: 'file name',
        http: {source: 'form'}
      }
    ],
    returns: {
      arg: 'fileObject',
      type: 'object',
      root: true
    },
    http: {verb: 'post'}
  });
```